# Optimize groovy for low-end hardware

Tags: groovy

I'm using `groovy` to run small scripts on a low-end `aarch64` machine, and startup is unexpectedly slow:

```
$ export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx384m"
$ time ./groovy -e "println 12345"
12345

real    0m18.661s
user    0m31.540s
sys 0m1.100s
```

Are there any System properties that I can try to speedup `groovy` startup and parser? Ideas?

Software: Groovy 4.0.6 / Java 17.0.5

```
$ ./groovy -version
Groovy Version: 4.0.6 JVM: 17.0.5 Vendor: Eclipse Adoptium OS: Linux
```

Hardware: Synology DS120J with some low-end 2-core `aarch64` CPU:

```
$ uname -a
Linux DS120J 4.4.180+ #42962 SMP Tue Sep 20 22:51:45 CST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux synology_armada37xx_ds120j
```

Comment: Compile scripts to classes better with @compilestatic where it's possible, run compiled code with pure java command line with only jars required...

Comment: I deployed a Vert.x-based app written in Groovy + MongoDB on a Raspberry Pi and it ran reasonably well

Comment: What `time ./groovy -e "println 12345"` do you get on the Raspberry Pi? Which model?